# Bash Code with while, list and crontab command

Tags: bash, while-loop, cron

I have something like this :

```
all_scripts=()

for i in "${OS_USER[@]}"; do

list_script=$(crontab -u $i -l | grep -o '[^ ]*\.sh' | grep -o '^[^ ]*' | sort -u)
```

I want to create a list ( all_scripts) which contain all scripts from all users

For example
if in user 1 crontab there are script1.sh , script2.sh
in user 2 there are scrip3.sh, script4.sh, script5.sh
and in user 3 script6.sh

I want a list with all scripts : script1,sh, script2.sh, script3,...script6.sh

Comment: WHat you have looks close. What is the problem? Don't make readers guess. Please show your required output from a small sample set of data, your current output from that same input and any error messages you're getting. Good luck

Comment: Each crontab line is already a script (with no name). Bash scripts do not have to contain ".sh" in their name but they can contain whitespace. What is the script name in this line: `* * * * * < /tmp/script1.sh var=script2.sh env` ?

Comment: please update the question with the contents of a sample `OS_USERS[]`, the associated `crontab` listings, a complete/working set of code (current code is incomplete), the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1):

What you presented is incomplete.  What you have is *almost* all correct.

You need to include the action ... to build the list ... within the loop.
You also need to initialize list_script as an array.
You probably want to suppress the "no crontab for ..." messaging.
You also need to be selective regarding which fields are "harvested" from the crontab, so ... ignore comments and ignore parameter definitions.

I recognize that the below may not correctly handle parameter definitions that may include spaces, but it is a good start for what you are looking for.  So, the end result would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## You may have a specific list instead of this next line.
OS_USER=( $(cut -f1 -d\: /etc/passwd) )  

all_scripts=()
list_script=()

for i in ${OS_USER[@]}
do
    list_script=$(crontab -u $i -l | grep -v '^#' | awk '{
        pos=index($0, $6) ;
        $0=substr($0, pos) ;
        print NF ;
        for( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++){ 
            if( index($i, "=") == 0 ){
                print $i ;
                break ;
            } ;
        } ;
    }' | grep -o '[^ ]*\.sh' | grep -o '^[^ ]*' | sort -u )
    all_scripts=( ${allscripts[@]} ${list_script[@]} )
done
print ${allscripts[@]}
```